# How to use bash shell builtin commands in own shell in C?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I'm on 1st year of IT Studies and I've got an exercise. I have to write my own shell for Linux using C. I have a few points to do, and one of them is my shell has to use 2-3 of shell builtin commands from man bash. 
How can I implement this functionality to my code? By using functions like system() or execl() or isn't it correct in this case and there are any other options?

Comment: Which builtins? Do you get to pick? `cd`, `echo`, `exit`, `kill`, `pwd`…

Comment: Good question. I received email with guidelines and one of them was  "Supports two other built-in bash shell commands (section "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" in man bash)". That's all.
I wanted to use smth like pwd or ls.

Comment: The five there are probably good ones for you to look into, then.

Comment: Are they bash builtin commands? I'm looking at this page at now and they are 2 sections: Bash builtins and Bourne shell builtins. Is that the same?
 
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands

Comment: I would imagine you're meant to write your own version of those builtin functions rather than spawning bash to call them

Comment: Oh. That would be. So when I will use getcwd() It would be just 'my version' of pwd? I thought I should just call any bash function from outside of my shell.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(I am understanding you are asked to implement your *own* tiny unix shell; this is a very good but common exercise)</sup>

Most of the time, you *cannot* use `bash` [*builtin* commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) (e.g. `cd`, `ulimit`, etc...) in your own shell. And you should not use `bash` or `/bin/sh` thru [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) but use directly [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) etc..., and implement your own [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) (see [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)).

As an example, you have to *explicitly* implement some `cd` command (calling the [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) system call) yourself in your shell. Because the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is a specific property of every process (so each process has its *own* working directory). See also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

That is why you *cannot* implement your `cd foo` by doing `system("cd foo")`, since [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) starts a separate, new, `/bin/sh` process (and the `cd foo` would only `chdir` in that new `sh` process, not in yours).

Most Unix shells are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). Feel free to study their source code. Consider also using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) they are doing.

Read also some book on Linux programming (e.g. [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) or something newer). See also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) and the `man` pages referenced from them.

Comment: I would study some books with pleasure, but I receive this task 3 days ago and I have to send it until monday. At the university from October we were learning only simple commands like copying files, chmod, chdir, etc. And a few things about bash scripting. So this task is quite difficult for me and I'm searching Internet now to understand that what I need to do this.

Comment: Then study the source code of some existing shell, notably `sash` (whose code is really small). And do spend a few hours reading relevant chapters of ALP (or any other Linux programming book). You need to learn, and to increase your skills

Comment: Yup, I know. 
I'm looking at projects on github to understand something. I think reading code which someone else wrote is a good idea. I did most of guidelines like setting environment variables or changing directory but this one is a problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to code a shell able to execute bash command in C. In that case:

You can use Execve (man execve), it is able to run bash command

You can find the path in your env. (main(int ac, char** argv, char** env))

You have to use fork() when you run a command, because execve() close your prog.

Comment: No; wrong! the OP is *coding* his own (tiny) shell, `bash`-like but a lot simpler (e.g. similar to `sash`)